# Ng mouse-leave does not trigger with nested li-ul

Tags: angularjs

I have a nested ul-li structure. I have mouseover & leave at each li. 'mouseleave' gets triggered when ever I move out of li but not if I move to inner ul within li. Here is my plunker. For eg in below if I move from parentli to childul it does not trigger mouseleave.  But If i move out of parentli completely it triggers mouseleave. Any help appreciated.

http://plnkr.co/edit/xPXC78xJ9EqXGEOmOI3G?p=preview

```
<ul>
    <li id="parentli" ng-mouseenter="showXBtn=true" ng-mouseleave="showXBtn=false">
      <p >Hide</p>

      <button ng-show="showXBtn"><span>x</span></button>
      <ul id="childul">
        <li ng-mouseenter="inner=true" ng-mouseleave="inner=false"> <p>Inner li</p><button ng-show="inner"><span>x</span></button></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: It should not trigger because the `<li id="parentli" .. ` is the parent so `ng-mouseleave` will call when mouse leaves the element, but if u hover the child its still on the parent element thats why its not going to trigger.

Comment: I agree but I have saw an example with jquery where its working http://jsfiddle.net/Jj8B5/9/

Comment: its a `jquery` example and what they did in the example is attach a `class` on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` states.

Comment: @Kalava you may notice that the example you mentioned also has `event.stopPropagation()` calls in `mouseover` handlers. http://plnkr.co/edit/sM8lDFaweECDbtwrsuTe?p=preview works as you want.

Comment: good one @YauheniLeichanok I think you can remove the `$event.stopPropagation()` in the parent as `<li ng-mouseover="showXBtn=true" ng-mouseout="showXBtn=false">` http://plnkr.co/edit/WJz5wywy2x8VrLzZXeo3?p=preview

Comment: @K.Toress I guess yes if you only have two levels in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

It should not trigger because the `<li id="parentli" ..` is the parent so `ng-mouseleave` will call when mouse leaves the element, but if u hover the child its still on the parent element thats why its not going to trigger.

so

```
<ul>
    <li ng-mouseenter="showXBtn=true" ng-mouseleave="showXBtn=false">
      <p >Hide</p>

      <button ng-show="showXBtn"><span>x</span></button>
      <ul>
        <li ng-mouseenter="inner=true; showXBtn=false" ng-mouseleave="inner=false; showXBtn=true"> <p>Inner li</p>
        <button ng-show="inner"><span>x</span></button></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

toggling the value of `showXBtn` when the hover of child element will resolve the issue.

```
<li ng-mouseenter="inner=true; showXBtn=false" ng-mouseleave="inner=false; showXBtn=true">
```

when `ng-mouseenter` on the child element we are going to set `inner=true` that will shoe the button in child element, and then set `showXBtn=false` which is going to hide button inside the parent element.

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/kcVWWGqikKF6ah3b4xEj?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Toress thanks for the explanation. The Demo link points to a different post.